# How to split values separated by comma and keep its row correspondence in excel

Tags: excel, string, split

In Excel 365, I have data in this format:

[image: Input format Image]

Or, in text:

```
1,2,3,7 A
4       B
5       C
6, 8    D
```

And I'm trying to split the data so it becomes this:

[image: Output format Image]

Or, in text

```
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   C
6   D
7   A
8   D
```

The leftmost row is always composed by numbers separated by comma or a single number. The right row can be any data.

Comment: This would be a great usecase for PowerQuery > Split by comma's into new rows. A few clicks which would do exactly what you are after.

Comment: PowerQuery worked perfectly for my case. Thank you very much.

Comment: If that solved the problem, perhaps @JvdV could rewrite the solution as an answer, and then Rebarba could [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it?

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code will do most of what you want:

```
Sub ExpandRows()

    Dim R As Range
    Dim Rw As Range
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim J As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Dim S As String
    Dim Tokens(1 To 1000) As String
    Dim NTokens As Integer
    Const Delim As String = ","
    Dim StartSize As Integer
    Dim TopCell As Range
    Dim BotCell As Range
    
    Set R = Selection
    Set TopCell = R.Cells(1, 1)
    Set BotCell = R.Cells(R.Rows.Count, 1)
    
    StartSize = R.Rows.Count
    For I = StartSize To 1 Step -1
        S = R(I, 1)
        If (S <> "") Then
            J = 0
            NTokens = 0
            Do
                K = InStr(J + 1, S, Delim)
                If (K = 0) Then
                    NTokens = NTokens + 1
                    Tokens(NTokens) = Mid$(S, J + 1, Len(S) - J)
                Else
                    NTokens = NTokens + 1
                    Tokens(NTokens) = Mid$(S, J + 1, (K - J - 1))
                    J = K
                End If
            Loop Until (K = 0)
        End If
        If (NTokens > 1) Then
            For J = NTokens To 2 Step -1
                If (Tokens(J) <> "") Then
                    Set Rw = R.Cells(I, 1).EntireRow
                    Call Rw.Select
                    Call Rw.Copy
                    Call R.Cells(I + 1, 1).EntireRow.Select
                    Call Rw.Insert(xlDown)
                    If (I = 1) Then
                        Set TopCell = TopCell.Cells(0, 1)
                        Set R = Range(TopCell, BotCell)
                    End If
                    Call R.Select
                    Call R.Cells(I + 1, 1).Select
                R(I + 1, 1) = Tokens(J)
                End If
            Next J
            R(I, 1) = Tokens(1)
        End If
    Next I

End Sub
```

This code will split the cells and create new rows with a single entry.

To use it, select the first column and execute the method.

After that, all you have to do is sort on the first column.