# Separating #'s from a column into multiple rows while preserving + copying the original row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using Excel scripts/macros.

I was given an excel sheet with roughly 60,000 rows. In every row, column "M" has multiple part numbers within it. Some of the part numbers are separated by spaces, others are separated with commas.

Data Before Separation:

[image: Data Before Separation]

I was instructed to create a new row for every individual part number. The new row has to copy the row it was on, for each part that is separated. Example below:

Data After Being Separated Properly:

[image: Data After Being Separated Properly]

As a result I have been doing this by hand... but some rows have 50+ parts within column M. I have to copy paste the row 50 times, and delete the unwanted numbers. At this rate, it may take months to complete. Unfortunately I do not have programming experience, so I don't even know where to start. I hope the images are at least helpful.

Comment: Look into PowerQuery > Split into new rows!

Comment: This is far too onerous to do by hand. I'd do this with VBA personally (but then I don't know what PowerQuery is!). Getting a full script written for you here is rather tricky - could you approach one of the freelancer platforms and pay someone to write a script?

Comment: PowerQuery is an Excel add-on that will do this automatically. Or you could look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274253/how-to-split-values-separated-by-comma-and-keep-its-row-correspondence-in-excel/70363609#70363609 where this a VBA code in one of the answers that will also do the job.